# Jest Error: Expected '{', got 'namespace' ... Using namespace and @Injectable

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, namespaces, nestjs

I'm using: NestJS and I have a class exported using namespace. Right after the export namespace I have the NestJS **@Injectable** decorator and I get the following error when I try to run the test: ***× Expected '{', got 'namespace'***

**Without *@Injectable* the test runs without problems, but I need Injectable.**

Class with Injectable

```
export namespace SearchCase {
    @Injectable()
    export class SearchCase {

        constructor(private casesRepository: InterfaceRepository<Case.Case>) { }

        async execute(request: RequestSearchCase): Promise<ResponseSearchCase> {
            const searchResult = await this.casesRepository.search(request.search);

            return {
                searchResult,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
describe('Search Case', () => {
    it('should be able return a case with substring', async () => {
        const casesRepository = new InMemoryCaseRepository();

        const searchCase = new SearchCase.SearchCase(casesRepository);

        const createCase = new Case.Case({
            utente: 'utente test',
            caseOrigin: 'case origin test',
            reportingDate: new Date(),
            reporterName: 'Emanuela Xavier',
            disease: 'disease test',
        })

        await casesRepository.create(createCase);
        
        const response = await searchCase.execute({
            search: 'Ema'
        });

        expect(response.searchResult.length).toBe(1);
        expect(response.searchResult[0].reporterName).toContain('Ema');
    });
});
```

**ERROR**
[Error shown when I run the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuGiG.png)

Removing @Injectable the test works without problem, but I need to use it.

Comment: Why did you create the instance manually?

Comment: Why are you using a `namespace`? I'm not sure if decorated classes inside a namespace are supported by Typescript

Comment: @JayMcDoniel It works fine. I've tested it a long time ago with NestJS.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then it's something about how `ts-jest` is interpreting the code

Comment: Really the "problem" was in the test runner. I was using swc instead of ts-jest and when I switched to ts-jest it worked again.

Comment: For me was utilizing an unsupported typescript operator like `satisfies`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using SWC/Jest instead of ts-jest, when I switched to ts-jest in my jest.config.ts the tests came back working even though I was using @Injectable.

I still don't understand why with **@swc/jest** it's failing, but for now it's working, when I have time I'll research more to find out the error.

**Configuration with @swc/jest not working**
*Archive: jest.config.ts*

```
"transform": { 
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": ["@swc/jest"]
}
```

**Configuration with @SW/jest that work**
*Archive: jest.config.ts*

```
"transform": { 
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
}
```